# How do I click the Home, Trending, and Subscriptions buttons on YouTube with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

Beginner here. I'm trying to grab the CSS Selectors for these buttons on youtube, and click them with Selenium. All three share the same Selectors, so not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: You forgot to post your code. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and add your code (as a [mcve]). What happens when you run it? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using this selector:

```
#sections a[title="Home"]
```

`#sections` is sidebar and `a` is link to page where `[title="home"]` is attribute of "a" tag.

So here is example code in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://youtube.com'
driver.get(url)
home_page_selector = '#sections a[title="Home"]'
trending_page_selector = '#sections a[title="Trending"]'
home_page_a_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(home_page_selector)
trending_page_a_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(trending_page_selector)
trending_page_a_element.text
trending_page_a_element.get_attribute('href')
home_page_a_element.get_attribute('href')
```

you can perform more operations on variables. Such as clicking. This may not work if Youtube isn't in English.

Comment: Thank you, was this something that could be copied straight from the Developer Tool? If not where could I learn more about this syntax? Appreciate it.

Comment: i target element using [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp), For example i wanted to see sidebar of youtube if it have ID for targeting because IDs are unique. So, first i target the element which is with [ID](https://i.imgur.com/bEPvI6L.png) and then i straight target anchor tag with its attribute title. You can use **element selector** in chrome developer tools [see](https://i.imgur.com/7NU0Lo7.png?1) for selecting element easily for watching their sibling tags, attributes and styling etc.